# joomla dynamic dropdown registrationform

Tags: drop-down-menu, joomla

1) I have a basic Joomla form that has three drop downs for Country, Town and Shop 
2) I need to get the dropdown list based on the  dropdown list provided above.

I have achieved to get the data from database and create drop down by coding in registration.xml in 
usercomponent

**What needs to be achieved:**
I am trying to create dynamic drop downs based on the above data selected in the dropdown.

Please help me I am working hard for this I couldn't find the solution and code break through

Answer (score 1):

I've created a basic non-Joomla example of this here

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $username = "USERNAME";
    $password = "PASSWORD";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("DATABASE", $dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `values`");
$values=array();
$counter=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $values[$counter]=$row{'country'};
   $counter++;
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
        <?php
            $i=0;
            $countries=array();
            foreach($values as $value) {
                $exists=false;
                if(count($countries)>0) {
                    foreach($countries as $something) {
                        if($something==$value) {
                            $exists=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($exists==false) {
                    $countries[$i]=$value;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        ?>
    <select id="first-choice">
        <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
        <?php
            $k=0;
            while($k<count($countries)) {
                echo "<option value='".$countries[$k]."'>" . $countries[$k] . "</option>";
                $k++;
            }
        ?>
    </select>

    <br />

    <select id="second-choice">
        <option>Please choose from above</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <select id="third-choice">
        <option>Please choose from above</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#first-choice").change(function() {
        $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?country=" + $("#first-choice").val());
    });
    $("#second-choice").change(function() {
        $("#third-choice").load("getter.php?town=" + $("#second-choice").val());
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

File called getter.php

```
<?php
    $username = "USERNAME";
    $password = "PASSWORD";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("DATABASE", $dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");

    if($_GET['country']) {
        $countries = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['country']);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `values` WHERE country='".$countries."'";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $values=array();
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           $values[$i]=$row{'town'};
           $i++;
        }
        $i=0;
        $towns=array();
        foreach($values as $value) {
            $exists=false;
            if(count($towns)>0) {
                foreach($towns as $town) {
                    if($town==$value) {
                        $exists=true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if($exists==false) {
                $towns[$i]=$value;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $k=0;
        echo "<option selected value='base'>Please Select an Option</option>";
        while ($k<count($towns)) {
            echo "<option value=".$towns[$k].">" . $towns[$k] . "</option>";
            $k++;
        }
    } elseif ($_GET['town']) {
        $town = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['town']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `values` WHERE town='".$town."'";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        echo "<option selected value='base'>Please Select an Option</option>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option>" . $row{'shop'} . "</option>";
        }   
    }
?>
```

Based on the tutorial [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicDropdown/). To Joomla this up. You will need to put the getter.php file into the model and call it through JSON (with a suitable controller). Remember to replace all visable text with JText - so it can be made with a language file. You also need to add the jquery into the header with `JDocument::addScript` or if your using Joomla 3.0 then `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` suffices. Also you must connect to the database through Joomla using `JFactory::getDBO`

I've put a basic example of this [here](http://joomjunk.co.uk/web-design/demo/dropdown.php).

Some notes: You may wish to call a specific version of JQuery as its constantly being updated. 1.9.0 works fine - but I don't know what will be hosted on that link when 2.0.0 comes out and what browser compatibility will be included.

This assumes a database structure of just

`id country town shop`. of course I doubt your database schemes are that easy. So remember to adapt this as necessary.

Hopefully this should start you going :)